# Instagram real time updates

Tags: instagram

I am unable to receive real time media updates from Instagram API. I have been able to register my client application successfully . I have received the subscription ID after accepting the challenge(GET to call back URL is successful). I have tried to post updates from the account registered with the client application.Its a public account.

```
Code NameValueCollection subparamGet = new NameValueCollection();
subparamGet.Add("client_id", client_id);
subparamGet.Add("client_secret", client_secret);
subparamGet.Add("object", "user");
subparamGet.Add("aspect", "media");
subparamGet.Add("verify_token", "myVerifyToken");
subparamGet.Add("callback_url", "Callback_URI); 
WebClient subclient = new WebClient(); 
var subresult = subclient.UploadValues("api.instagram.com / v1 / subscriptions / ";, subparam);
```

I do not see any post to the call back URL for the notifications. Any pointers to this issue will be of great help

Comment: Can you post the code?. Also are you sure you have a successful connection established with the api?\

Comment: Yes connection to the End point is fine as I receive the subscription ID.

Comment: Code NameValueCollection subparamGet = new NameValueCollection();                subparamGet .Add("client_id", client_id); subparamGet .Add("client_secret", client_secret);
                subparamGet .Add("object", "user");
               subparamGet .Add("aspect", "media");
                subparamGet .Add("verify_token", "myVerifyToken");
                subparamGet .Add("callback_url", "Callback_URI);
                WebClient subclient = new WebClient();             
                var subresult =subclient.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/", subparam);

Comment: You are testing via server right(& not locally?). Take a look at : http://thegregthompson.com/old_site/instagram-real-time-api-php/ and see the detailed explanation..

Comment: The call back URL is publically accessible..I get the subscription ID.